# Techniques to draw a solid transparent cone

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I wrote this to draw a solid cone, but it looks a bit weird(see screenshots) as it just keeps drawing circles starting from base circle, until the current circle radius is small enough to form finally a cone.

```
void drawCircle(const GLfloat& r, const GLfloat& x0, const GLfloat& y0, GLfloat z0)
{   
    glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);      
        for (GLfloat ang = 0; ang <= 360; ang++)
        {
            glVertex3f(x0 + r*cos((ang*PI)/180), y0 + r*sin((ang*PI)/180), z0);
        }

    glEnd();
}

void drawCone(GLfloat r, GLfloat h, const GLfloat& x0, const GLfloat& y0, GLfloat z0)
{
    glColor4f(0.0, 1.0, 1.0, ALPHA);
    GLfloat i = r/h;
    while (h--)
    {
        drawCircle(r-= i, x0, y0, z0++);
    }
}
```

So what are another techniques/algorithms to draw a transparent solid cone?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Draw your cone using triangles and use the technique descriped here:  http://prideout.net/blog/?p=51

Comment: Indeed, draw cone with triangles. For transparency I suggest [alpha blending](https://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/faq/technical/transparency.htm).

Comment: @stgatilov I tried with triangles before but blending hasn't made cone transparent with my drawing algo

Comment: @arammis: The problem with "transparency" is, that z-buffer depth testing and blending don't go together. You have to sort the surfaces to be drawn far to near and draw in that order. With convex shapes as your cone there's a small trick though: Use face culling to first cull the front faces (so only the far side backside faces of the cone are drawn) then switch culling to back face, so that only the front faces are drawn. Do this with blending enabled and you get a nicely blended cone shape. However it's only the outer surface, no solid. OpenGL itself doesn't know solids.

Comment: Thanks for your techinque! It really helped me in my project. I modified it a bit and I finally got a working cone!

Comment: @Yarik0urWorld glad it helped you :) feel free to upvote the question too :)